# GAE app gives error 500 on tomcat; Error running javac.exe compiler

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans, path, mapping

How can it be that Netbeans can compile and run apps, but that the path environmental variable for windows xp doesn't have javac configures correctly (assuming this to be the problem, see [GAE error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964709/google-app-engine-with-java-error-running-javac-exe-compiler))?

Following this [tutorial](http://rocky.developerblogs.com/tutorials/getting-started-google-app-engine-netbeans/), I'm getting runtime errors from a Java app.  I'm using NB 6.9.1 and the [GAE](http://kenai.com/projects/nbappengine/pages/Home) (Google App Engine) [third-party](http://www.mozgoweb.com/posts/google-app-engine-plugin-for-netbeans-6-9/) for the correct version.  I suppose I could compile the plugin from source, but I don't believe that's the problem.

As near as I can tell the [Guestbook](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating.html) app comes directly from Google for GAE.

------------update-----------------

OK, this looks like a path problem.  The output from [path](https://docs.google.com/document/d/14yH6BolQ4hZ5EoUEY59nxInDwefApjSjyujUx37f4WQ/edit?hl=en) shows that not all drives have the correct path.  (I manually added the JDK path to the path for the c drive.)  The spammy output for the [GAE](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16C1h0kbhhEyGW8FPCgSMjT6aT-yMGE0XS0rh5uGP_gU/edit?hl=en) is seperated, as is the spammy [run](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13R_yjJbjY-mNc-xELsOnGIG1XXCGCrp18sO4bg9pOfE/edit?hl=en) output.

I think it's just the network mapping, which is breaking the path(?).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In terms of setting the path the default in the computer lab is:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

H:\>echo %PATH%
C:\apps\java\java-tools\ant\bin;c:\apps\java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin\bin;C:\watcom-1.3\b
innt;C:\watcom-1.3\binw;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
c:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;c:\apps\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Program Files\Microso
ft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Apps\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Windows Im
aging\;C:\Program Files\FreePhoneLine\native\Xuggle\bin\

H:\>
```

After editing, the new path result is:

Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

H:>echo %PATH%
C:\apps\java\java-tools\ant\bin;c:\apps\java\jdk1.6.0_14\bin\bin;C:\watcom-1.3\b
innt;C:\watcom-1.3\binw;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
c:\Program Files\Intel\DMIX;c:\apps\QuickTime\QTSystem\;c:\Program Files\Microso
ft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Apps\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Windows Im
aging\;C:\Program Files\FreePhoneLine\native\Xuggle\bin\;C:\Program Files\Java\j
dk1.6.0_02\bin

H:>

All well and good.  Further good news:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

H:\>javac -version
javac 1.6.0_02

H:\>
H:\>D:

D:\>javac -version
javac 1.6.0_02

D:\>
D:\>C:

C:\>
C:\>javac -version
javac 1.6.0_02

C:\>
```

So, it **appears** that javac is on the path correctly now.  By putting the NetbeansProjects directory (now called NB) and the GAE sdk on C:\ the app actually runs.

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

H:\>c:

C:\>dir
 Volume in drive C is SE14L0130-31
 Volume Serial Number is 0896-E6F1

 Directory of C:\

01/15/2010  09:21 AM                 0 1
11/17/2010  11:55 PM    <DIR>          appengine-java-sdk-1.3.8
08/10/2009  11:56 AM    <DIR>          Apps
05/05/2006  07:17 AM                 0 AUTOEXEC.BAT
08/25/2009  09:34 AM    <DIR>          bd4a6caba48fb59236110a4fc495
09/17/2009  07:47 AM    <DIR>          config
05/05/2006  07:17 AM                 0 CONFIG.SYS
01/06/2010  10:43 AM    <DIR>          dell
11/17/2010  04:10 PM                 0 dfinstall.log
11/17/2010  11:04 PM    <DIR>          Documents and Settings
05/10/2006  12:16 PM    <DIR>          Inetpub
01/06/2010  10:43 AM    <DIR>          Intel
05/16/2006  07:18 AM    <DIR>          lexmark
11/17/2010  11:57 PM    <DIR>          NB
10/22/2008  08:18 AM    <DIR>          NDPS
11/17/2010  04:45 PM        16,336,664 Persi0.sys
11/17/2010  11:50 PM    <DIR>          Program Files
11/17/2010  04:00 PM    <DIR>          quarantine
11/17/2010  11:58 PM    <DIR>          temp
08/10/2009  09:40 AM    <DIR>          watcom-1.3
11/17/2010  07:18 PM    <DIR>          WINDOWS
12/26/2008  03:30 PM    <DIR>          Zenworks
05/10/2006  06:39 AM            12,814 ziswin.hst
               6 File(s)     16,349,478 bytes
              17 Dir(s)  178,861,129,728 bytes free

C:\>
```

All this is so anticlimactic to futzing about with PATH, not really sure what think.

Anyhow, kinda work.  Dunno, really, if this is a factor of simply moving the project to the C drive, the sdk to the C drive, just a different machine, or factor x.

For now at least, solved.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely a problem of using the JRE instead of the JDK.  As to how to configure that in NetBeans, I can't say. :(

Answer (score 2):

One bet on lack of PATH environment configuration